# Update join table attributes with has many => through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My controller action:

```
def updating_rating
    input = params[:recommendation_ratings].values

    input.each do |mini_params|
      rating_id = mini_params[:rating_id].to_i
      recommendation_id = mini_params[:recommendation_id].to_i
      puts rating_id
      puts recommendation_id
      rr = RecommendationRating.find_or_create_by_rating_id_and_recommendation_id(rating_id, recommendation_id)
      rr.update_attributes(:rating_id => rating_id, :recommendation_id => recommendation_id )
    end
   redirect_to :back, :flash => { :notice => "Rating Submitted." }
  end
```

I am passing in the params from a form_tag in my view. The code works as expected when creating a new relationship, however if you try to update a value and resubmit the form, it adds a new rating, rather that updating the existing rating.

So for example if you have a product with a rating of 1, and change the rating to 2 and resubmit the form, that product will have ratings of 1 and 2. What do I do to update an existing rating, rather than adding an additional rating to a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that rating_id is the actual rating that you want to save.  With this assumption in mind,

```
rr = RecommendationRating.find_or_create_by_rating_id_and_recommendation_id(rating_id, recommendation_id)
```

will find first a `RecommendationRating` which has a `rating_id` of the new rating value.  If it can't find any it will create one.  You can fix this by just finding a `RecommendationRating` first and build a new one if it's not existing

```
rr   = RecommendationRating.find_by_recommendation_id(recommendation_id)
rr ||= RecommendationRating.new(recommendation_id: recommendation_id)

rr.rating_id = rating_id
rr.save
```

If you have associations, it will look cleaner (i'm assuming a `has_one` relationship here because we're only talking about 2 columns)

```
reco = Recommendation.find recommendation_id
rr   = reco.recommendation_rating || reco.build_recommendation_rating

rr.rating_id = rating_id
rr.save
```